# How to slice between m and n in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an observable which fetches a list of data. I am getting tricked with the `slice` pipe provided by angular though it's not the tough one. Below is my example:

```
value$: Observable<number[]>;
// this is present in TS. Let's say this fetches an array with value as [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Now what I want is to divide this array in 3 different div's of which first one will take first 6 elements, the last will take the last 3 elements and the second one will take the elements present between the first 6 and the last 3. So for this I have written the below logic:

**Div 1**

```
<div *ngFor="let ele of value$ | async | slice: 0:6">...</div>
// This is working fine
```

**Div 2**

```
<div *ngFor="let ele of value$ | async | slice: -4:6">...</div>
// This is not working fine
```

**Div 3**

```
<div *ngFor="let ele of value$ | async | slice: -3">...</div>
// This is working fine
```

Here the second `div` is not working as expected rather it's taking some values from first `div`.

Can anyone point me out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: _the second one will take the elements present between the first 6 and the last 3._   There are no elements between the first 6 and the last 3. There are 9 elements.

Comment: if there are the is my logic correct? and also if suppose the above criteria doesn't meet then after showing the first 6 in div 1 will it show the rest in div 2 and div 3 will be blank?

Comment: The elements after the first six and before the last three would be `slice(6, -3)`. Not `slice(-4, 6)`.

Comment: let me check with this

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way to achieve this is using splice since you don't the size of the second array supposing your array size is dynamic.
The biggest problem is your inital set contain only 9 elements so the first one take 6 the last take 3 and there's nothing left and looking back for -4 index you find the last index of the first array.

By using splice you achieve the same result and showing exactly the first 6 and the last 3.

[image: Suggested Code]

whenever you run into any doubts about functions you could go into
[Slice - mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

[Splice- mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: thanks clause for your response but am using ```slice``` pipe with ```ngFor``` in angular so can't accept the answer for now :(

Comment: Nothing stops you from handling data before in the ts onInit or something, defining each array beforehand and select your data